# In Swift, does the compiler give you implicit access to the value you're switching on?

Tags: swift, variables, switch-statement, implicit

A cool feature of Swift is it gives you a lot of implicit variables, such as these:

- `value` in a `set` statement.
- `oldValue` in a `didSet` statement.
- `error` in a `catch` clause.

I'm wondering if the `switch` statement has something similar. Don't think so, but wanted to ask.

For instance, take the following code (assume there is an enum that defines a calculated `displayName` property).

Note how I have to explicitly create a temp variable to hold the result of the function since I have to use it both to switch on, and also down in the case statements below...

```
let valToSwitchOn = getValToSwitchOn()

switch valToSwitchOn {
    case .categories: return categories.count > 0 ? valToSwitchOn.displayName : nil
    case .narratives: return narratives.count > 0 ? valToSwitchOn.displayName : nil
}
```

However, if Swift offered an implicit variable for the switched-on value, it would simplify the code, like so *(Note: I'm using `switchValue` here as an example)*...

```
switch getValToSwitchOn() {
    case .categories: return categories.count > 0 ? switchValue.displayName : nil
    case .narratives: return narratives.count > 0 ? switchValue.displayName : nil
}
```

This lets me feed the switch directly with the function without having to first create an explicit variable as the switched-on value is provided implicitly for me.  Not that big a deal if I do (it's only one line) but I was wondering if there was something like that already.

So does Swift have an implicit variable for `switch`?

Comment: What is `switchValue`? and where you are returning the value to?

Comment: switchValue is a stand-in for what I'm looking for... an implicitly-defined variable representing the value the cases are checked against. Look at the second example... the value you're switching on is returned from a function. I'm wondering if the compiler gives you access to that value without you having to explicitly define it yourself.

Comment: Added more to the question to clarify.

Comment: If the value you are switching is an `enum`. how will it have a `displayName`?

Comment: You can add functions and calculated properties to an enum. It's pretty convenient.  That said, that's off-topic from what I'm asking, which is if there's an implicit variable that feeds the switch.

Comment: No as far as i know there isn't. I was trying to think of a workaround by understanding what you actually need it for.

Comment: Not a 'need' any more than explicitly creating the other variables are.  It's easy to get around... just use the temp variable.  But if the compiler provides something for me, why write the extra code?  That's why I never explicitly define/name my setter variable or the error in a catch clause, even though one could.  Just extra stuff in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an 'implicit' variable for a switch, as you're use the case statements to check against the value for the switch.

Comment: Yes, but in my example, the value comes from a function. I'm just wondering if I always have to create a temp variable so I can use it in the case statements.  Was hoping the compiler gave it to me. Guess not.